# Separate Solr results for multiple hits within a Solr field?

Tags: solr

Say I have a field in Solr called, "OCR_text".  If the field OCR_text, for a give <doc>, contains a string like, "This is foo bar, my foo bar finds foo bars for others.", is it possible to have separate and unique responses from Solr for each instance of "foo" in OCR_text from the same <doc>?

Currently, if I were to search for "OCR_text:foo", I would get only one response from that , even though "foo" is contained within multiple times.  I have a method for iterating through instances of "foo" within that singular response and creating unique results that way, but the overall "numFound" for a query does not reflect the *total* amount of times "foo" is found in a given <doc>.

I have a feeling this is either a very simple way of constructing Solr queries I'm not familiar with, or a fundamentally more complex problem.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "numFound" part only shows you the number of documents, not the total amount of hits in a single field or in a single document. For finding total hits, you need to use TermVectorComponnent, which are briefly explained [here](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+Term+Vector+Component) and [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent) . You can also dig the [maliling list](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-User-f472068.html) for more details and example implementations.

Comment: I'm making progress, but having a hard time actually getting results in the termVectors portion of the response.  Below is a selection of the result, where both "Imagina_OCR_HTML_5" and "Imagina_OCR_HTML_5" should have multiple instances of the word, "the".  Any thoughts on why that might be the case?

<lst name="doc-3008">
<str name="uniqueKey">Imagina_OCR_HTML_5</str>
</lst>
<str name="uniqueKeyFieldName">id</str>
<lst name="doc-3011">
<str name="uniqueKey">Imagina_OCR_HTML_8</str>
</lst>
<str name="uniqueKeyFieldName">id</str>